# After downloading 2 applications download the phone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I uploaded the game I made in Unity to google play. But I have a problem. After downloading the game from google play, 2 applications are downloaded to the phone. When you press the second one, the game does not open.What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the second game wasn't a test/debug version that was previously existing on the phone? delete them both and try again

Comment: Do you have a custom AndroidManifest.xml? If so please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play will only download a single apk and install it on your phone.

Most likely you had a previous debug version of your game, installed through unity that was already there.

Comment: I installed the game for the first time on google play.I installed apk via unity to test my game before the game is over and I dont have a problem.But I installed it on Google play as aab.When I download the game, it lands on my phone in 2 applications. If I delete one, the other is deleted, but only one of them opens the game.

Comment: Hmm that is interesting. Have you tried downloading it into another phone to see it does the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried on more than 10 phones and the result is the same. There is such a place inside the Android manifest: android: label = "mygamename". Whatever I write here, this is the name of the 2nd app that lands on my phone. If I delete this section from the Android manifest file, I can't get the aab extension.